# How can I get rows with specific columns and specific pattern?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a csv file looks like this:(second column is date pattern)

```
qqq.eee,2015-10-12
rrr-ttt,2015-11-23
aaapppp,2022-01-10
ddd_fff,2017-05-23
zzzbbbb,2013-09-20
nnnmmmm,2015-06-17
wwwwwww,2014-11-20
uuu-uuu,2016-12-10
ppppppp,2015-10-19
kkkkkkk,2016-12-25
```

I want to get rows that second column matching as follows:

```
year between two number(for example): 2014<= year =<2016
month between two number(for example): 10<= month =<12
day between two number(for example): 20<= day =<30
```

and then get output as follows:

```
rrr-ttt,2015-11-23
wwwwwww,2014-11-20
kkkkkkk,2016-12-25
```

Is this possible with awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just compare from the end to the beginning because of the separators

```
awk -F[-,] '$NF >= 20 && $NF <= 30 && $(NF-1) >= 10 && 
            $(NF-1) <= 12 && $(NF-2) >= 2014 && $(NF-2) <= 2016' yourfile
```

1. `NF` is the last field and `$NF` is the value, and `$(NF-1)` is the value for the field before the last and so on
2. `$NF` day, `$(NF-1)` month, `$(NF-2)` year

Answer (score 4):

`awk` is best suited for column and multiple condition filtering. However, this particular problem can be also solved with `grep`

```
$ grep -E '201[4-6]-1[0-2]-(2[0-9]|30)$' ip.csv 
rrr-ttt,2015-11-23
wwwwwww,2014-11-20
kkkkkkk,2016-12-25
```

- `-E` use extended regular expressions
- `201[4-6]` range of 2014 to 2016
- `1[0-2]` range of 10 to 12
- `2[0-9]` range of 20 to 29

  - using grouping and alternation, `(2[0-9]|30)` gives the range 20 to 30
- `$` end of line
- further reading: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html